# jquery click - unable to see why click won't work

Tags: jquery

Hoping someone can see what i can't here - the jquery is being loaded in the head. The premise is to be able to select colour swatches from a list provided. I've added the rendered html below to illustrate correctly filled value.

```
<script>
// choose default colour subcolors
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul.colourcategory_swatch li[data-value=<?php echo   
$defaultColorCategory ?>]').click()
});
</script>

 <ul class="colourcategory_swatch">
 <?php $attribute =   
Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 
'colourcategory'); ?>
 <?php foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as  
$option): 

if(!empty($option['value'])):$backgroundColor = split('#' , 
$option['label'] ); ?>
                                           <?php 
                                               $attId = 
$attribute->getId();
                                               $filter_id = 
$option['value'];
                                               $subcolors = 
Mage::getStoreConfig('color_selector_plus/layerednavopts
/filter_'.$attId.'_'.$filter_id.'_layereds', Mage::app()->getStore());
                                           ?>
                                           <li data-subcolors="<?= 
$subcolors ?>" data-value="<?= $option['value']?>" style="background: 
#<?= $backgroundColor[1]?>" title="<?= $option['label']?>"
                                           <?php 
if($defaultColorCategory == $option['value']):?> class="selected"<?php 
endif;?>></li>
                                       <?php endif;endforeach; ?>
                                   </ul>
Rendered html:
<div class="input-box">
<input id="colourcategory" class="input-text required-entry error"    
type="hidden" value="12" name="product[colourcategory]">
<ul class="colourcategory_swatch">
<li class="selected" title="Black #1C0F0A" style="background: #1C0F0A" 
data-value="12" data-subcolors="36"></li>
```

Comment: Provide HTML markup and code as rendered in the browser

Comment: I don't see a function after the `.click` event handler, so nothing will happen, and you need a semicolon after the closing paranthesis of the .click handler

Comment: @AbdulAhmad the click() will work ..

Comment: Your jquery code will not actually bind something to the `click` event but instead trigger it. You need to provide an argument to the `click()` function that will handle the event.

Comment: I see what you mean about providing the argument, but the script above is working in one site as expected but not in another - it looks like it's something to do with how the jquery is called or a jquery/prototype conflict (but no errors are shown). On click the value is filled - I've added the correctly rendered html above.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax must be:

```
$('your selector').click(function() {/*do something here*/});
```

so no wonder it does not do anything.